# What's a null string in bash

Tags: bash

I've just found this snippet in the bash manual:

```
A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form

  name=[value]

If value is not given, the variable is assigned the null string.
```

What exactly is meant by `null string`? Is e.g.

```
local empty
```

equivalent to

```
local empty=""
```

?

Comment: Beside the point, but  `local empty` is not always equivalent to `local empty=""`. For example, if you enable `set -u`, then in the first case, references to `$empty` will fail, while in the second case they won't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A "null string" is one which has zero length. In your example, both are the same.

A simple test:

```
#!/bin/bash
go(){
   local empty
   local empty2=""
   [[ -z $empty ]] && echo "empty is null"
   [[ -z $empty2 ]] && echo "empty2 is null"
   [[ $empty == $empty2 ]] && echo "They are the same"
}

go
```

prints:

```
empty is null
empty2 is null
They are the same
```

Comment: “A "null string" is one which has zero length” is not true though. `test` has different expressions for testing if a string is not the null string (`[ <string> ]` ) and has non-zero length (`[ -n <string> ]`) and you can see that these are different by comparing the output of `[ ] && echo "true"` with the output of `[ -n ] && echo "true"`.

Comment: Hmm, ok, after a deeper look, apparently `[ -n ]` is not using `-n` as an operand, but is rather using the first form of the test to test the string "-n". Nevertheless, there are places in the bash documentation that seem to explicitly mention both null and empty strings in a single sentence, which, to me, implies that these are different. Or I’d like to see something in the docs that supports the claim that “the null string” is the same as “the empty string”.